# Can we update the Azure Cosmos Account location?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created the Azure Cosmos DB Account in West US region. But, for some reasons, I would like to move it to East US. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the ARM tracked resource (i.e. the account) is not currently supported and today customers will need to create a new account and manually migrate data.

There is a doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-move-regions) that describes the steps to do this.

PS: This capability will be available in the future.